# Playback Screen Showing Too Much Information (Histogram Display)

Tags: rear-lcd, histogram, preview, thumbnail-preview

I'm unsure why my playback screen on my Sony a7 III is showing so much information. It's difficult to see the pictures I'm taking because the image shows up so small.

I can use the AF-ON button to zoom in. When I do that it zooms in really far and then I have to use the AEL button to zoom out to see the picture properly. It's really tedious and I'd like to know how to change my settings so it simply displays the photo!

I went through the manual and it has a page that shows this setting, but not how to change it.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check out the 'Help Guide' [here](https://helpguide.sony.net/ilc/1720/v1/en/contents/TP0001653116.html). It states

> Press the DISP (Display Setting) button.
>
> To switch the information displayed on the viewfinder, press the DISP button while looking into the viewfinder.
>       Each time you press the DISP button, the screen display changes.

and pressing the DISP button cycles the display through the following screens

> During playback (Monitor/Viewfinder)
>
> Display Info. → Histogram → No Disp. Info. → Display Info.
>
> If the image has an overexposed or underexposed area, the corresponding section will blink on the histogram display (overexposed/underexposed warning).
>       The settings for playback are also applied in [Auto Review].

Answer (score 1):

Here are the step-by-step instructions on how to switch the display options for a photo on your Sony Alpha a7 III camera:

- Turn on the camera and enter the playback mode by pressing the "Playback" button.
- Select the photo you want to view by using the control wheel or the arrow buttons.
- Press the "DISP." button on the back of the camera to cycle through the available display options. Each time you press the button, the display will change to show different information.
- The available options include:

  - Image only
  - Image with shooting data
  - Image with a histogram display
  - Image with a brightness histogram
- Press the "Menu" button to return to the playback menu.
- Press the "Playback" button again to exit the playback mode.

Answer (score 0):

You could have mentioned the type of your camera or shown a photograph with all its backside controls.  The four-way controller has "DISP" in its upper direction, presumably you can use that (when the playback display is unzoomed) to choose the amount of displayed information.

Comment: You could have looked at the picture - it clearly says Sony  7 III

Answer (score 0):

> It's difficult to see the pictures I'm taking because the image shows up so small.

I'm going to toss out a challenge to your assumption. Keep the image small.

If you're shooting RAW, then what you're seeing is the camera's processed version. You are probably likely to adjust the settings in Post-Pro, furthering the look of your final image from this preview anyway.

The size is enough for you to quickly judge your composition and move on.

I don't know Sony but on my Canon, there is a zoom button to quickly get to 100% to check focus.

Learn to use the histogram to check your exposure.

So, by having the image small, you can:

- See the histogram, ensuring a proper exposure was taken (one can actually be fooled into thinking that an underexposed shot is okay by a too-bright preview)
- See enough of the image to check composition
- Have a single button press to check focus
- Confirm any other setting you may have overlooked (ever set your ISO to 3200 for shooting at night, grab your camera the next morning, and forget to lower it? The info makes it easy to catch that mistake)

If, instead, you had the preview image taking the whole screen, then you'd be toggling through items in order to get to this information or you'd be trusting the preview image (which, like I said, you should never do).